# Notation for switches in ladder notation

Tags: schematics, ladder, math-notation

I was reading https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-10/monostable-multivibrators/,

and at the bottom of the page it has

[image: Example ladder diagram]

I read their page on switch notation, but it did not say what the arrows, like the weird one for TD1 means. So what is the difference between the switch TD1 and TD2 on the second line?

Answer (score 0):

TD1, 2nd line, normally close time delay to open

TD2, 2nd line, normally closed, time delay on close

TD2, 3rd line, normally open, time delay on open